# Determine text inside a DIV is in Bold

Tags: javascript

I have a HTML structure like below

```
<div>Some text</div>
<div class='inBold'>Hello <b>Dude</b></div>
<div class='inBold'>Hello <span class="boldText">Dude</span></div>
<div class='inBold'>Hello <strong>Dude</strong></div>
```

and CSS is

```
.boldText{ font-weight : bold; }
```

Now I just wanted to check whether a string Dude is in bold of all DIVs. It seems like dealing with HTML would be messy as there are so many ways to give bold formatting. How can I identify whether some text inside a DIV is in bold or not. Please help me on this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/about

Comment: @Xotic750 Where does that link apply to the current context?

Comment: "Stack Overflow is a question and answer site", there has been no activity in two weeks, did you find a solution? If it was none of those suggested below, then perhaps you could share your answer, and even mark it as the answer you selected to your question. "This site is all about getting answers", quotes are from link above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps like this, this selects each element on the page and then checks it's [computed style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/window.getComputedStyle) for [font-weight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/font-weight) set as ´bold´ (can also be by ´[b](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/b)´ or ´[strong](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/strong)). If it matches this rule then the element is logged to the console.

Note: getComputedStyle detects 'b' and 'strong' and so no extra tests are required to detect those elements.

CSS

```
.boldText {
    font-weight : bold;
}
```

HTML

```
<div>Some text</div>
<div class='inBold'>Hello <b>Dude</b>
</div>
<div class='inBold'>Hello <span class="boldText">Dude</span>
</div>
<div class='inBold'>Hello <strong>Dude</strong>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("*"), function (element) {
    if (window.getComputedStyle(element).fontWeight === "bold") { // can also use .getPropertyValue("font-weight")
        console.log("bold: ", element);
    }
});
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/3bsQa/)

Of course this is checking everything on the page but it is fairly simple to look for your required text and check just those elements using this principle.

By changing to this line:

```
if (element.textContent === "Dude" && window.getComputedStyle(element).fontWeight.toLowerCase() === "bold") {
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/2jUhB/)

Note: getComputedStyle is not supported on older browsers, and neither is [Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

document.querySelectorAll is also not supported on all older browsers.

There are plenty of shims out these for Array.forEach, or alteratively you can change it to a for or while loop.

getComputedStyle is s little more of a problem, but if you need something that is more cross browser, then this should give you wider support.

Javascript

```
function walkTheDOM(node, func) {
    func(node);
    node = node.firstChild;
    while (node) {
        walkTheDOM(node, func);
        node = node.nextSibling;
    }
}

function textContent(node) {
    if (typeof node.textContent !== "undefined" && node.textContent !== null) {
        return node.textContent;
    }

    var text = ""

    walkTheDOM(node, function (current) {
        if (current.nodeType === 3) {
            text += current.nodeValue;
        }
    });

    return text;
}

function camelCase(string) {
    return string.replace(/-([a-z])/g, function (matched) {
        return matched[1].toUpperCase()
    });
}

function getComputedStyleProperty(element, property) {
    if (!window.getComputedStyle) {
        if (document.defaultView && document.defaultView.getComputedStyle) {
            return document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(element).getPropertyValue(property);
        } else {
            var camelCased = camelCase(property);

            if (element.currentStyle) {
                return element.currentStyle[camelCased];
            } else {
                return element.style[camelCased];
            }
        }
    } else {
        return window.getComputedStyle(element).getPropertyValue(property);
    }
}

var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("*"),
    length = elements.length,
    i = 0,
    element;

while (i < length) {
    element = elements[i];

    if (textContent(element) === "Dude" && getComputedStyleProperty(element, "font-weight") === "bold") {
        console.log("bold: ", element);
    }

    i += 1;
}
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/teNp4/)

Answer (score 3):

```
var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('inBold');
for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++)
    console.log(isBold(divs[i]));

function isBold(node){
     var childNodes = node.childNodes;
     for(var i = 0; i < childNodes.length; i++)
         if(childNodes[i].nodeType != 3 && (childNodes[i].className.indexOf('boldText') != -1 
            || childNodes[i].tagName == 'B'
            || childNodes[i].tagName == 'STRONG'))
             return true;
     return false;
}
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MMwe8/4/)

Comment: This looks for a specific class name or element type rather than in a generalised manner. But nice still the same

Comment: getElementsByClassName is not supported by older browsers, but there are plenty of shims out there. Care must be taken using indexOf on the className string, as there could be for example a class named "boldTextItalic", and that would also match, but it would not necessarily be bold.

Answer (score 2):

This will create a treeWalker and check for each node with text content "Dude" for bold propriety regardless of the className or tagName:

```
var treeWalker = document.createTreeWalker(document.body, NodeFilter.SHOW_ALL, filter, false);

function filter(node) {
    if (node.textContent === 'Dude') {
        var computed = window.getComputedStyle(node, null);

        if(computed && computed.getPropertyValue("font-weight")=== "bold"){
            return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT;
        }

    } else {
        return NodeFilter.FILTER_SKIP;
    }
}

while(treeWalker.nextNode()) {
    //    Elements with bold text
    console.log(treeWalker.currentNode)
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bxcTp/1/

Comment: +1 for using the fast and often forgotten TreeWalker, though it must be noted that this is not supported by older browsers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/window.getComputedStyle) function to determine the current value of an element. This includes any inherited values from parent elements:

```
// get a pointer to your element somehow
var elem;

// get the current weight
var weight = window.getComputedStyle(elem,null).getPropertyValue("font-weight");
```

A "mapping" form the numeric values to identifiers like `bold` can be found in the [MDN article on `font-weight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/font-weight#Values).

Comment: It is also worth noting that ´getComputedStyle´ is not supported on older browsers, and on some older internet explorer versions you need to use ´currentStyle´

Answer (score 0):

If you can use jQuery you can use this sample:

```
var consideredBoldsSelector = 'b, strong, span.boldText';
var expectedCount = $("div.inBold").length
var bAllMatched = $("div.inBold *:contains('Dude'):first-child").filter(consideredBoldsSelector).length === expectedCount
```

With `expectedCount` you can manipulate how many "hits" you're expecting, and with consideredBoldsSelector you can easily add css-alike selectors for your bolds.

Note that :contains is case-sensitive.

Comment: Example of it working, although you must specify what is to be considered "bold" rather than detecting it: http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/EeBJH/