# How to get value from innerHTML object?

Tags: javascript, json

I need get parameter from json page, i can execute code on that page,

```
alert(document.body.innerHTML)
```

shows:

```
<pre style="word-wrap:break-word;white-space: pre-wrap;">{"token": " ... "}</pre>
```

how to get token from this innerHTML object?

Its in child browser of my cordova app, thats why i need to use such a bad way.

Comment: @DanielA.White It crashes, and I cant see error.

Comment: Learn to use the [`document object methods`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document) and then use [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) on the JSON text to get a javascript object, then access as normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `JSON.parse` with `querySelector` and `innerHTML`

```
var obj = JSON.parse(document.querySelector('p').innerHTML);
```

Why I am using `innerHTML` is there are cross-browser issues when it comes to `textContent` or `innerText`

Comment: While this works in this example I would say that this is a sloppy method for general purpose use, one on which I would not rely upon. Better would be to collect the values of the `textNode`'s of the element. [`texcontent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent)is pretty well supported if you are not worried about IE9 and older.

Comment: One example of getting `textContent` which is also cross browser can be seen in this answer, amoung aother here on SO. http://stackoverflow.com/a/16300534/592253